# junit executes each line two times

Tags: spring, tomcat, junit

Running up Junt test on my project each code line is executed two times, as in stack trace below:

```
 TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.PostsServiceImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.PostsServiceImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.PostsDAOImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.PostsDAOImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.PostsDAOImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.PostsDAOImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.PostsServiceImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:10:39 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.PostsServiceImpl.findPostsByPrimaryKey]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.social.FacebookServiceImpl.storePostsFromPages]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.social.FacebookServiceImpl.storePostsFromPages]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.social.FacebookServiceImpl.storePostsFromPages]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.social.FacebookServiceImpl.storePostsFromPages]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.TagServiceImpl.findTagsByUserprofileId]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.service.TagServiceImpl.findTagsByUserprofileId]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 DEBUG [main] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.TagDAOImpl.findTagByUserProfileId]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionAspectSupport - Getting transaction for [it.stasbranger.spidly.dao.TagDAOImpl.findTagByUserProfileId]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
22 apr 2013 21:11:31 TRACE [main] TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a6c891] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@b9b8d9] bound to thread [main]
```

In Tomcat server.xml autodeploy is disabled. 
Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

```
# STDOUT appender
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %p [%t] %C{1} - %m\n

# use the STDOUT appender. set the level to ERROR.
log4j.rootLogger=STDOUT

log4j.category.atomikos=WARN, STDOUT
log4j.category.org.springframework=WARN, STDOUT
#log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=ERROR, STDOUT


# use this category for skyway / spring util output
log4j.category.org.skyway.spring.util=WARN, STDOUT

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.logger.social=INFO, social
log4j.appender.social=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.social.File=/home/###############
log4j.appender.social.File=spidly.log
log4j.appender.social.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.social.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%t] %C{1} - %m\n
log4j.appender.social.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.social.MaxBackupIndex=10

# temp log for rss
log4j.logger.rss=INFO, rss
log4j.appender.rss=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rss.File=/home/#######################
log4j.appender.rss.File=rss.log
log4j.appender.rss.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rss.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%t] %C{1} - %m\n
log4j.appender.rss.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.rss.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have duplicate log appenders. Check your log4j configuration (or logback or whatever your using).

See [Log4j appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) or [Logback appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

Also try turning on Log4j debugging on by setting the system property `-Dlog4j.debug=true`

Comment: I'm a developer... I never assume :) Paste your log4j xml or properties in your question. You mention Tomcat. How are you running Tomcat with your unit tests? Cactus? Embedded Tomcat?

Comment: # STDOUT appender
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %p [%t] %C{1} - %m\n
# use the STDOUT appender. set the level to ERROR.
log4j.rootLogger=STDOUT
log4j.category.atomikos=WARN, STDOUT
log4j.category.org.springframework=WARN, STDOUT
..........
I'm using embedded tomcat into eclipse

Comment: Please paste it into your original question. I can't tell where the newlines are in the above comment.

Comment: Hmm its been a while since I have used the log4j properties format. I would just try and remove the log4j.properties all together and see what happens. I did notice thats its printing DEBUG for Spring classes when you have them marked for WARN. Also `category` is really a `logger`.

Comment: No sorry for spring log level is DEBUG!